# VueJS Router, ленивая загрузка маршрутов, Loading chunk 0 failed

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, lazyloading

Использую Vue Cli

Пытаюсь создать ленивую загрузку компонентов следующим образом:

```
router/admin/index.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

function lazyLoad(component){
    return() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "/chunk/" */ '../../components/' + component)
}

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/admin',
        component: Dashboard,
        name: 'dashboard',
        meta: { title: 'Dashboard' },
    },
    {
        path: '/admin/devices',
        component: lazyLoad('Admin/Devices.vue'),
        name: 'devices',
        meta: { title: 'Devices' },
        children: [
            {
                path: ":id",
                component: lazyLoad('Admin/Devices/Device.vue'),
                name: 'device',
                meta: { title: 'Device' },
            }
        ]
    }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
})

export default router
```

После компиляции в папке chunks появляются файлы с названием от 0 >.
При обращении к роуту выскакивает 404 ошибка, так как не правильно указан path

https://host.ru/js/0.js

А должен: https://host.ru/public/vue/dist/js/chunk/...

Вопрос: Где нужно указывать path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смог решить проблему следующим путем:

в файле **vue.config.js** указал путь к скомпилированным файлам

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/public/vue/dist',
}
```

В файле где прописываются роуты изменил

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
})
```

на

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/',
    routes
})
```